# Parse query string to objects node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I've got a get request looking like this:

```
/api/stores?offset=10&limit=15?order=+name?filter=name='Tesco|distance=4
```

I need to parse +name from my query to object looking like: `{name: 1},` if +  before name, and `{name:-1}` if - before name.  And filter query should look like `{name:'Tesco',  distance:4}`

Can anyone help me to do it in order to reach best performance

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is sending you that garbage URL should be punched, if you have no chance of changing it, you can use this hack.

```
var url = "/api/stores?offset=10&limit=15?order=+name?filter=name='Tesco|distance=4";
var m = url.match(/name='(.+?)\|distance=(\d+)/);
console.log(m[0]); // returns name='Tesco|distance=4
console.log(m[1]); // returns Tesco
console.log(m[2]); // returns 4 as a string value
```

Using m[1](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options) and m[2] you can build a new object.

Seriously that URL is trash, fix that problem if you can and you can use a non-hack to get those values and build your object with [querystring.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options).